# Why are Uber Api Time Estimates returning 0 results

Tags: objective-c, uber-api

Using GET /v1/estimates/time on postman returns results under "times" but calling it using xcode/objC returns empty results.

parameters are exactly the same and product_id is omited.

I was using afnetworking 3.0

Comment: Are you authenticated in Postman? Are you authenticating with the Objective-C code? What other steps are you taking? Please provide more detail.

Comment: +1 please provide example code and we can help. I see the same response from three test clients (afnetworking + okhttp + curl).